# How to run pip installed elasticsearch?

Tags: python, django, linux, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm trying to use Django + Haystack + Elasticsearch.

So I installed Elasticsearch 2.4 with pip becouse Django gave me errors about that it can't import Elasticsearch. Now it can and I can run `./manage.py rebuild_index` in my Django project and it gives this output:

```
Indexing 23 journal entrys
GET /haystack/_mapping [status:404 request:0.006s]
```

but only if I somehove run elasticsearch. So I installed elsasticsearch2 from AUR packages as well and run that. But as I suspected when I try to get all documents by running: `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v"` which returns:

```
health status index    pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
yellow open   haystack   5   1          0            0       795b           795b
```

If  I understand correctly it is empty.
I went where pip installs packages(`/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages`) and found two folders related to Elasticsearch:

```
elasticsearch
├── client
│   ├── cat.py
│   ├── cluster.py
│   ├── indices.py
│   ├── ingest.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── nodes.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── cat.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── cluster.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── indices.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── ingest.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── nodes.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── snapshot.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── tasks.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── utils.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── snapshot.py
│   ├── tasks.py
│   └── utils.py
├── compat.py
├── connection
│   ├── base.py
│   ├── http_requests.py
│   ├── http_urllib3.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── pooling.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       ├── base.cpython-36.pyc
│       ├── http_requests.cpython-36.pyc
│       ├── http_urllib3.cpython-36.pyc
│       ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│       └── pooling.cpython-36.pyc
├── connection_pool.py
├── exceptions.py
├── helpers
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── test.cpython-36.pyc
│   └── test.py
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── compat.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── connection_pool.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── exceptions.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── serializer.cpython-36.pyc
│   └── transport.cpython-36.pyc
├── serializer.py
└── transport.py

elasticsearch-2.4.1.dist-info
├── DESCRIPTION.rst
├── INSTALLER
├── METADATA
├── metadata.json
├── pbr.json
├── RECORD
├── top_level.txt
└── WHEEL
```

I don't see a `start_elasticsearch.sh` or `bin/elasticsearch` so how can I start it?

Comment: You need to first install the Elasticsearch binaries, which are not written in Python - see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/_installation.html . Once you have done that you need to start the elasticsearch service so that your Python code can reach it.

Comment: @solarissmoke I think I did that already by installing Elasticsearch2 from AUR packages. Because if you download one of Elasticsearche's provided downloads(.zip, .tar, .deb, .rpm or .msi) they are not installable, you just extract the conntent and run `elasticsearch` or `elasticsearch.in.sh`. And if I do so I still get `GET /haystack/_mapping [status:404 request:0.006s]`. Regardles of my hoppes for Elasticsearch I just  tried out Whoosh and it works so for now I'll use that.